# Searching Large number of Arguments (Java/Derby/Lucene)

Tags: java, lucene, derby

I have a Java application (developed by a third party, I do not have the source code) which I know is using Derby databases and Lucene indexing.

The application UI allows searching; for example, the following syntax is allowed:

```
guid: (5ec3419a-1cfa-4e65-9c3d-617134c22ccb OR  b804abcb-2e01-48ec-8220-98c9e4778737)
```

A similar search works fast if the number of listed guids is lower than 25,000-30,000. However, everything greater than 100,000 takes more than 2 days to complete.

Any starting point on how to improve the search performances? We do not have dev support for the Java application anymore.

Comment: Without access to source code to make changes, I'm not sure there is much that can be done.  If the internal structure of the program was understood there might be some syntax changes that could be made to speed up the search, but that is a big might.

Comment: Are you saying that in the query `guid: ( g1 or g2 )`, you are trying to list 100,000 separate guids, all OR'd together?

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton: Yes, my query will have 100,000 separate guids, all OR'ed together.

Comment: @Joe, of course this will be terribly slow, if you will enter 100.000 ORs together, no way you could change the speed in this case.

Comment: @Mysterion: I see...thank you for the input